# integration between bmc remedy and serviceNow using wso2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

we would like to integrate incident module between BMC Remedy and ServiceNow ITSM applications using ESB-WSO2, need assistance on this to achieve this integration.

Use case: Service now has to create incident then WSO2 will consume the request and process then processed request will be send to Remedy. This is nothing but a e-bonding or you can call it as ticket replication.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: We need more details. Can Service now send a SOAP or REST request? Can BMC Remedy receive SOAP or REST request? Describe their interfaces. Show the format of a message. Is it XML or JSON? etc...

Comment:  Both Servicenow and Remedy are ITSM applications. Both can consume and receive REST request
 We are trying to integrate incident module using WSO2, We are going to use JSON format
 Basically we are trying to achieve e-bonding functionality with this integration, 
Company ABC uses ServiceNow as their incident management system and BMC Remedy as their issue tracking system. When there is a ServiceNow incident created, a related Remedy ticket needs to be created

Comment: This is a time-consuming process that needs someone with the domain knowledge and technical knowledge to integrate these systems. But with WSO2 ESB, its connectors and ESB tooling you can easily automate         the process. It provides an easy way of configuring the integration solution through graphical representations.
 Please find below sample JSON formats of BMC Remedy and ServcieNow

Comment: As far as I see, you need just a simple API. It will receive a call in a Servicenow format Json, transform it into BMC's and send it to BMC backend endpoint. On receiving a response, it will transform it back to Servicenow format and send it back to Servicenow .

Comment: can you please describe in detail how we can achieve this in ESB WSO2? is it through connectors, but we didn't find any BMC Remedy connector available in WSO2 store? please advice..

Comment: You have to create an API and call it fron Servicenow side. You can read in details about APIs in documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+APIs Where's no need in connectors, just standard mediators.

Comment: i want to send a rest request to serviceNow from wso2 how can i achieve it please provide some DOC which can help me with the flow

Comment: how do you want to invoke a call to serviceNow from wso2? By Schedule or by sending a request from client?

Comment: Sending a request from client sending message from wso2->serviceNow getting response from serviceNow

Comment: servicenow creates ticket then it should comes to WSO2 and the same message needs to be forward from WSO2 to BMC Remedy

Comment: we are trying other possibility also as below but getting error.

1) Trying to get response from servicenow by using servicenow connector
2) We have added a service now connector in our workflow
3) We have created a proxy service below is the source

Comment: <proxy name="SNOWPS" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_a72c854f-a57c-4a4c-9fa9-faa1a6cdebac">
            <address uri="https://dev85868.service-now.com"/>
        </endpoint>

Comment: <inSequence>
            <servicenow.init>
                <serviceNowInstanceURL>https://dev85868.service-now.com</serviceNowInstanceURL>
                <username>rest_test</username>
                <password>12345678</password>
            </servicenow.init>
            <servicenow.postRecord/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
           <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>

Comment: 4) When we are trying to use this services via (try this service )(response error: <Reason>Error connecting to the Tryit ajax proxy</Reason>)
5) please suggest us how to move forward

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample API for you. Supposing that you have already installed ServiceNow connector.
You can call it from Postman using GET or browser, http://{yourWso2EiServer}:8280/serviceNow/test
After testing you can change method to POST and try to send different messages using POSTMAN. Then you will have to evaluate properties from a message, using like"expression"="json-eval($.tablename)" instead of "value"= in you Property mediators and your message must be an application/json and contain this field, like
{"tablename":"incident"....

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ServiceNowApi" context="/serviceNow" version-type="context">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test" outSequence="" faultSequence="">
      <inSequence>
    <property name="tablename" value="incident" description="here you can set your request variables with constants for test or read it from request using json-evalng "/>
    <property name="sysparmDisplayValue" value="true"/>
    <property name="sysparmFields" value="short_description,number,sys_id"/>
    <property name="sysparmView" value="short_description,number,sys_id"/>
    <property name="number" value="12345678"/>
    <property name="shortDescription" value="Testing integration using ServiceNow connector"/>
    <property name="active" value="true"/>
    <property name="approval" value="owner"/>
    <property name="category" value="inquery"/>
    <property name="contactType" value="phone"/>
         <servicenow.init>
         <serviceNowInstanceURL>dev85868.service-now.com</serviceNowInstanceURL>
         <username>rest_test</username>
         <password>12345678</password>
         </servicenow.init>
         <servicenow.postRecord>
           <tableName>{$ctx:tableName}</tableName>
        <sysparmDisplayValue>{$ctx:sysparmDisplayValue}</sysparmDisplayValue>
        <sysparmFields>{$ctx:sysparmFields}</sysparmFields>
        <sysparmView>{$ctx:sysparmView}</sysparmView>
        <sysparmExcludeReferenceLink>{$ctx:sysparmExcludeReferenceLink}</sysparmExcludeReferenceLink>
        <sysparmInputDisplayValue>{$ctx:sysparmInputDisplayValue}</sysparmInputDisplayValue>
        <number>{$ctx:number}</number>
        <shortDescription>{$ctx:shortDescription}</shortDescription>
        <active>{$ctx:active}</active>
        <approval>{$ctx:approval}</approval>
        <category>{$ctx:category}</category>
        <contactType>{$ctx:contactType}</contactType>
        <apiColumns>{$ctx:apiColumns}</apiColumns>
         </servicenow.postRecord>
         </respond>
          </inSequence>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Error in wso2 tool:

[2019-08-09 13:57:39,476] [EI-Core] ERROR - ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the dev85868.service-now.com/api/now/table/? URL.
[2019-08-09 13:57:39,476] [EI-Core] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out

Comment: This is the code we are trying :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/now" name="Wso2SNOW" version-type="context" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/table/incident">

Comment: <inSequence>
            <property description="wso2test snow" name="tablename" scope="default" type="STRING" value="incident"/>
            <property name="shortDescription" scope="default" type="STRING" value="test between wso2serviceNow"/>
            <property name="number" scope="default" type="STRING" value="12345678"/>

Comment: <servicenow.init>
                <serviceNowInstanceURL>dev85868.service-now.com</serviceNowInstanceURL>
                <username>Rest_test</username>
                <password>12345678</password>
            </servicenow.init>

Comment: <servicenow.postRecord>
                <tableName>{$ctx:tableName}</tableName>
                <sysparmDisplayValue>{$ctx:sysparmDisplayValue}</sysparmDisplayValue>
                <sysparmFields>{$ctx:sysparmFields}</sysparmFields>
                <sysparmView>{$ctx:sysparmView}</sysparmView>
                <sysparmExcludeReferenceLink>{$ctx:sysparmExcludeReferenceLink}</sysparmExcludeReferenceLink>

Comment: <sysparmInputDisplayValue>{$ctx:sysparmInputDisplayValue}</sysparmInputDisplayValue>
                <number>{$ctx:number}</number>
                <shortDescription>{$ctx:shortDescription}</shortDescription>
                <active>{$ctx:active}</active>
                <approval>{$ctx:approval}</approval>

Comment: <category>{$ctx:category}</category>
                <contactType>{$ctx:contactType}</contactType>
                <apiColumns>{$ctx:apiColumns}</apiColumns>
            </servicenow.postRecord>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>

Comment: <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

Comment: You have to use <serviceNowInstanceURL>https: //dev85868.service-now.com</serviceNowInstanceURL>,Provide protocol **https** in URL

Comment: <api context="/api" name="Wso2SNOW" version-type="context" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/now/{table}/incident">

is over uri-temlate Correct?

From postman
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Requested URI does not represent any resource: /now/table/",
        "detail": null

Comment: is over uri-temlate Correct? No, uri-template="/test" would be enough for test. Full API Url doesn't matter, it is hidden behind the scene by connector

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="wso2snow" startOnLoad="true" transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <servicenow.init>
                <serviceNowInstanceURL> https://dev85868.service-now.com</serviceNowInstanceURL>
                <username>rest_test</username>
                <password>12345678</password>
            </servicenow.init>
            <servicenow.postRecord>
                <shortDescription>TEST my WSO2</shortDescription>
            </servicenow.postRecord>

Comment: <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>

Comment: We are trying this with proxy services above is the code but facing error

Comment: [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[2019-08-14 15:42:37,122] [EI-Core] ERROR - StandardWrapperValve Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /admin/jsp/WSRequestXSSproxy_ajaxprocessor.jsp at line 223

220:             payloadElement = XMLUtils.toOM(getSecuredDocumentBuilder(true).

Comment: 220:             payloadElement = XMLUtils.toOM(getSecuredDocumentBuilder(true).
221:                     parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes())).getDocumentElement());
222:         } catch (Exception e) {
223:             throw new Error("INVALID_INPUT_EXCEPTION. Invalid input was : " + payload);
224:         }
225:     }
226: 


Stacktrace:] with root cause

Comment: ava.lang.Error: INVALID_INPUT_EXCEPTION. Invalid input was : {"short_description":"Testing the wso2"}
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:336)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)

Comment: Can any one respond on this we want to use wso2 as a broker which handles the request from serviceNow anf bmc remedy both are ticketing tools Example when ever BMC Remedy creates a ticket wso2 should pick the request and pass the request to ServiceNow and get the response to BMC remedy or when ever serviceNow creates a ticket wso2 should take the request and send it to BMC remedy and give back the response for that same to serviceNow. As we are very New for wso2 can any one share he source code or workflow images we kindly request please provide the full details